# UIImage in self sizing UITableViewCell stretching

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitableview

So I have a tableview setup so it displays some information text with an image, the text can vary so I've set up the constraints that the cell updates its size by itself, however the images are stretching as shown below and i've checked that the content mode is set to **Aspect Fit**.
[image: Image stretched]

As it can be observed from the image there are 3 Views in the cell:
-The Title
-The Image, which is being stretched
-The description

My constraints are set up as followed:

1. Title.top = topMargin
2. Title.trailing = trailingMargin
3. Title.leading = leadingMargin
4. Title.height = 32
5. Image.leading = leadingMargin
6. Image.top = Title.bottom + 16
7. bottom.margin = Image.bottom
8. Image.width = SuperView(content of cell).width * 0.4
9. text.leading = image.trailing + 16
10. trailingMargin = text.trailing
11. bottomMargin = text.bottom
12. text.top = topMargin + 16

How can I fix this issue so the images don't stretch? If any additional information is needed please ask and i'll add it.

Thanks
-Jorge

Comment: Have you tried setting the imageView to aspectFit

Comment: I've stated in the question that it is set to aspectFit, that's why i'm confused about the stretching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a height constraint to the image matching its width so that it maintains its square aspect ratio. Or any height for that matter. Just fix the height so that it does not stretch.

```
image.height = SuperView(content of cell).width * 0.4
```

Comment: But by doing this if there would be a lot of text the cell could not grow due to this constraint right?

Comment: Only if the cell height is bound to the image height.  I didn't see a constraint on the bottom of the image.  You could add one to the bottom of the cell with >= to allow the space to be larger.

Comment: Im not sure why this worked because before i've tried to add an aspect ratio with a multiplier of 1 and it gave me errors, however now with the height constraint it worked, that's odd. I will try it out with a larger text and see if it works with the other constraint(greater or equal to).

Comment: It should work unless there is a fixed constraint between the bottom of the image and the bottom of the content view of the cell.  This all being said, I have experienced serious issue using auto sizing table view cells in the past and have moved completely away from them to calculated cell sizes.  Greatly improved scrolling lag and performance.  Just food for thought

Comment: It can be quite difficult to set up, but with these new constraints it worked really well, even for larger texts, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For an app I just created, the tableViewCells and images exhibited something similar, stretching after the cell was scrolled off screen and back into view.

Assuming the image is retrieved from a server (or a file with image data), create a UIImage with a scale factor before setting it as the image of the UIImageView in the tableViewCell. I experimented with a few scale factors (instead of calculating, so your results may vary) before setting it as 5... it is better to calculate for production code but in prototyping, this heuristic worked:

```
 UIImage* scaledImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data scale:5.0f];
 // ... On MainThread
 [cell.imageView setImage:scaledImage];
```